# Can not find element using Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I want to click an element :

```
<td valign="top" class="bI">
    <div role="button" class="d-k-l b-c b-c-R xD" tabindex="0" 
     style="user-select: none;">Cancel</div>
</td>
```

I tried to use FindElementByXPath nad FindElementByClassName but it doesn't work

```
element = driver.FindElementByXPath("//td[@class='bI']//div");
element = driver.FindElementByXPath("//div[contains(@class, 'd-k-l b-c b-c-R xD')]");
```

How I can get this element. Thank you!

**Update:**
My element is under an iframe, now it's work. Thank you all!

Comment: What result you are getting ? Either element not found or Element is not clickable ?

Comment: @IshitaShah element not found

Comment: Try Explicit/Implicit wait or check whether button located inside frame/iframe

Comment: @Andersson Ahh, It's under an iframe. It's my mistake, Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

Use this Xpath :

```
//div[text()='Cancel']
```

If element is not visible then you should wait for some time until it's visibility by using Explicit wait.

Comment: your error trace please ? and check if it's in iframe ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this Xpath :

```
driver.FindElementByXPath("//td[@class='bI']//div[@class='d-k-l b-c b-c-R xD']").Click();
```

OR

```
driver.FindElementByXPath("//td[@class='bI']//div[contains(text(),'Cancel']").Click();
```

Comment: the class you are using d-k-l b-c b-c-R xD , is dynamic and should be avoided

Comment: If so. You can use second provision.

Comment: in that also you do not need to use contains(text(),'Cancel'), cause it's not sub part or something, I'm just giving my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Xpath

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='d-k-l b-c b-c-R xD']")).Click();
```

OR

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@text ='Cancel']")).Click();
```

OR

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='d-k-l b-c b-c-R xD'][@text='Cancel']")).Click();
```